# Testing invalid form submission with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I have a simple Cucumber test to see if, on entering invalid credentials, a user is sent back to the registration page.

My final step looks like this:

```
Then /^I should be on the registration page$/ do
  current_path.should == new_user_registration_path
end
```

However, when someone submits a form and it comes back with errors, they actually end up on "/users", and not "/users/sign_up"

I'm assuming this is because the user_registration POST method maps to /users. But I don't wait to test for /users, because that could theoretically be the index of users, which I don't want to be the error page.

Is there a better way to test form errors in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test that the page that user ends up on contains error text. Treat Cucumber tests as if you were testing manually: you wouldn't check the url after form submission, but you would look in the page content to understand if the submission was successful or not